# Getting err_sync_copy_null_node in aerospike. What does it mean?

Tags: debugging, aerospike

What does ***err_sync_copy_null_node*** actually signify. Not able to get some proper documentation. Any clues ?

Comment: Maybe this helps? https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/getting-lots-of-err-sync-copy-null-node-error-in-aerospike/1574

Comment: Also seems like version 3.6.0 has a fix for something that may be related: (KVS) AER-4237 - Fix for err_sync_copy_null_node (Which version are you running?)

Comment: Using 3.5.9. Tried to restart the principal node. The issues still persisted. A rolling cluster restart seemed to work.

Comment: Still not sure about the root cause.

Answer (score 1):

Since you indicated you are running version 3.5.9, you are likely hitting the bug mentioned in my comment, and that was addressed in 3.6.0:

- (KVS) AER-4237 - Fix for err_sync_copy_null_node

The root cause is a bug in the code. From our internal bug database, it seems to be related to some counter overflow. So upgrading to a [recent version](http://www.aerospike.com/download/server/latest) should hopefully take care of this.